# Have two login buttons in the same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In login page two buttons are used to authorize a user, one button for Lecturer  and other button for student, how can a single button use to execute lecturer and student  using if else statement... this project uses C# ASP.NET

Student

```
protected void log_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["id"] = txtId1.Text;
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
    com.CommandText = "select [id], [name],[password], [rol] FROM [Student] WHERE [id] =@id AND [password]= @pass";
    com.Parameters.Add("@id", txtId1.Text);
    com.Parameters.Add("@pass", EncryptPassword(txtPass1.Text));
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd.Read())
    {

        var _id = rd["id"].ToString();
        var _role = rd["rol"].ToString();
        var _fname = rd["name"].ToString();

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(

           1,
           _id,
           DateTime.Now,
           DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
           true,
           _role + "." + _fname,
           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hashed_ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashed_ticket);

        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        // Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Profile.aspx");

        if (_role == "student")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Student/Profile.aspx");

        }


        rd.Close();
        conn.Close();


    }

    else
    {
        lb1.Text = "Invalid username or password.";

    }
}
```

Lecturer

```
protected void btLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["id"] = txtId.Text;
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand com = conn.CreateCommand();
    // conn.Open();


    com.CommandText = "select [id], [fname],[password], [role] FROM [Lecturer] WHERE [id] =@id AND [password]= @pass";
    com.Parameters.Add("@id", txtId.Text);
    com.Parameters.Add("@pass", EncryptPassword(txtPass.Text));
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd = com.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd.Read())
    {

        var _id = rd["id"].ToString();
        var _role = rd["role"].ToString();
        var _fname = rd["fname"].ToString();

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(

           1,
           _id,
           DateTime.Now,
           DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1),
           true,
           _role + "." + _fname,
           FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hashed_ticket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashed_ticket);

        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        // Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Profile.aspx");

        if (_role == "Admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Profile.aspx");

        }

        else if (_role == "Lecturer")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Lecturer/CS.aspx");
        }

        rd.Close();
        conn.Close();


    }

    else
    {

        lb.Text = "Invalid username or password.";

    }


}
```

How to execute student and lecturer login buttons using one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you want 3 tables, and let user to enter username and password only. Once user is authenticated, redirect to a page based on the user's authorized roles.

- Users Table
- UsersInRoles Table
- Roles Table

However, it is out of your original question.

### Back to Original Question

You need RadioButtonList or DropDownList to select the type of person. Then change the CommandText based on the selection.

[image]

Comment: the answer is understood in how to design the page but do not know how to make the code based on user tables

Comment: According to my understanding of your question, you have two tables - Student and Lecturer. You need to assign query to **CommandText** based on user's selected value.